# How to get indexOf of matching chracters

Tags: javascript, indexof

I want to get `indexOf` of all occurring characters.

For Example, I have a variable `a`

```
var a = "aabaaababaa";
```

I want to get `indexOf` for all characters in `a`

I tried:

```
for(i = 0; i < a.length ;i++){
   var len = a.indexOf(a);
   console.log(len);
}
```

But it returns `indexOf` for the first character only.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/g8kpwnw8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the second argument to `indexOf` ([specification link](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.7), [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)). The second argument is the index at which to start looking. So use the value from one loop, plus one, as the starting point for the next search. Also, look for the *string* `a`, rather than using your variable `a` at the first argument (e.g., by putting `a` in quotes):

```js
var a = "aabaaababaa";
var index = -1;
while ((index = a.indexOf('a', index + 1)) != -1) {
  snippet.log(index);
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you look for a longer string, depending on whether you want to match *within* that string on subsequent loops, you might either add 1 each time (as above) or add the length of what you were looking for.

Answer (score 3):

you can do a loop like this one, indexes will contain all the indexes.

```
var a = "aabaaababaa";
var indexes = [];

for(i = 0; i < a.length ;i++){  
    if(a.charAt(i) == "a") indexes.push(i);
}

console.log(indexes);
```

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/lyncee/b65qo5bb/

Comment: Not a bad idea. Since `indexOf` can be optimized, it may be slower than `indexOf`, but the code is simpler. Simple is good.

Answer (score 1):

With var len = a.indexOf(a); you are looking for the index of the variable, so it will be always return 0 in this case, because you are looking for the first index of a var in this var.

If you had something like: var c="dfaabaaababaa", and you use var len = c.indexOf(a); it would return 2.

So, you have to star looking in other index like: var len=a.indexOf(a, 2) (in this case it would return -1, because there are no coincidences) or you have to look for it in an other variable, which contains the variable you are looking for.

Another possible mistake (I don't know which result you want), is that you want to look for the character 'a'. In this case you need: 
    var len=[ ];
    for(i = 0; i < a.length ;i++){
     len.push(a.indexOf('a', i));
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
    for(i = 0; i < a.length ;i++){
       var len = a.indexOf(a[i], i);
       console.log(len);
    }
```

a is an array. you have to do a[i] to access to one char